# I m already having modal box with dynamic label which will show my all pop-ups in modal box.How to call that function in java script show alert?

Tags: javascript

My function for modal box and label

```
function test(strmsg) {

    //   alert(strmsg);
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    document.getElementById('<%=myID.ClientID%>').innerText = strmsg;
    btn.click();

}
```

AND POP-UP is,

```
static public void ShowAlert(System.Web.UI.Page p, string sMsg, string sKey)
{
     string sScript;

     sScript = string.Format("<script language='javascript'>test(strmsg)
               </script>", sMsg);
     // sScript = string.Format("<script 
     language='javascript'>alert('{0}');</script>", sMsg);
     p.RegisterStartupScript(sKey, sScript);
}
```

Comment: look at the code highlighting ... does that look right to you?

Comment: I took hidden button which will automatically get clicked through java script whenever pop-up is called and and show strmsg in dynamic label on modal box.

Comment: the code still looks invalid - please **check the formatting**

Answer (score 0):

Create an onclick event listener and call the function that you created with that.

```
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

btn.onclick = function() {
    showPopUp();
};

function showPopUp() {
    // Show your pop-up elements or alert();
};
```

For dynamic messages, you can add a hidden element somewhere where you assign the message from the backend. Then, just get the text data from it when ever you call the event.